# Lenovo laptop Fn Ctrl swap doesn't work for some shortcuts

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, lenovo-laptop

So I have set up Ubuntu 14.04 on a new Lenovo E540 and choose the BIOS option to swap the <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys. This works well but there are some quirks.

It appears Lenovo has introduced some extra keyboard shortcuts at BIOS level in v2.13, such as <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Now with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> buttons switched in BIOS, the shortcuts are still triggered when pressing the physical <kbd>Fn</kbd> key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in software). This means pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is intercepted and interpreted as <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> by the BIOS, and my code isn't saved. Has anyone dealt with this issue? Waiting for Lenovo to update the BIOS with a fix could take years.

I think the only solution is to switch the buttons back in BIOS and learn to live with the keyboard layout.

Comment: Live with it :) It's not that hard to adapt.

Comment: @kamil, that's the current plan, and I'm getting used to it surprisingly quickly. But I will try and file a bug report with lenovo as it is a usability bug

Comment: Looking at [this thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/Thinkpad-E540-Bios-update-2-09-Ctrl-and-Fn-swap-bug/td-p/1631270), the solution can be to downgrade BIOS to 2.08.

Answer (score 3):

BIOS version 2.16 (10/30/2014) fixed this issue finally :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, let me try out that BIOS update this evening, it will be the second time I boot into Windows on this laptop